# Add a node at the end of all branches in a treeview

Tags: delphi, treeview, treenode

```
for j:=0 to TreeView1.Items.Count-1 do
 if (not(CNode.HasChildren) then
 begin
  CNode:=TreeView1.Items[j];
  CNode:=TreeView1.Items.AddChild(Cnode,'xxxx');
 end;
```

doesn't work obviously as the number of items in the tree increases every step.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to take a "snapshot" of the nodes and then add to the leafs, or ... It's not so clear. What is your motivation for this, maybe there's some other solution.

Comment: I mean take a snapshot of the tree as you mentioned and add a child to every leaf captured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imo, it is cleanest if you do this recursively, as in

```
procedure TForm1.AddChildren(ATreeView: TTreeView);

  procedure ProcessNode(Node : TTreeNode);
  var
    NewNode : TTreeNode;
  begin
    while Node <> Nil do begin
      if Node.HasChildren then
        ProcessNode(Node.getFirstChild)
      else
        NewNode := ATreeView.Items.AddChild(Node, 'Child of ' + Node.Text);
      Node := Node.getNextSibling;  
    end;
  end;

begin
  ProcessNode(ATreeView.Items[0]);
  ATreeView.FullExpand;
end;
```

, preferably bracketed between calls to Items.BeginUpdate/EndUpdate.  This way, you avoid the problem that you can get with the TreeView.Items.Count changing.

If you have to stick with using the TreeView.Items for some reason, you could do it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.AddChildren(ATreeView: TTreeView);
var
  List : TList;
  i : Integer;
  Node,
  NewNode : TTreeNode;
begin
  List := TList.Create;
  try
    ATreeView.Items.BeginUpdate;
    for i := 0 to ATreeView.Items.Count - 1 do
      List.Add(ATreeView.Items[i]);
    for i := 0 to List.Count - 1 do begin
      Node := TTreeNode(List.Items[i]);
      if not Node.HasChildren then begin
        NewNode := ATreeView.Items.AddChild(Node, 'Child of ' + Node.Text);
      end;
      Node.Expand(True);
    end;
  finally
    ATreeView.Items.EndUpdate;
    List.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Obviously this works by making a TList of the Tree's nodes and then iterating it to add the new children.

You could make this a bit more efficient by only adding the childless nodes to the List, but then fully expanding the tree correctly - if that's what you want - requires an extra step:

```
procedure TForm1.AddChildren(ATreeView: TTreeView);
[...]
    for i := 0 to ATreeView.Items.Count - 1 do begin
      if not ATreeView.Items[i].HasChildren then
        List.Add(ATreeView.Items[i]);
    end;
    for i := 0 to List.Count - 1 do begin
      Node := TTreeNode(List.Items[i]);
      if not Node.HasChildren then begin
        NewNode := ATreeView.Items.AddChild(Node, 'Child of ' + Node.Text);
      end;
    ATreeView.FullExpand;
  [...]
end;
```

Comment: thks for your quick reply. My solution was to repeat my loop until no childless children was found with no image attached and to attach the image to every childless child found after adding a child. But both solutions are cumbersome.

Comment: It's less cumbersome if you do it recursively - see update - which on reflection is how I should have done it in the first place.

Comment: oh Thks so much MartynA. Your code definitely works fine and it is not cumbersome ! On the contrary it is smart !

Comment: Actually, I doubt that the recursive way could be any shorter than it is. Anyway, please feel free to accept the answer (by clicking the 'tick' at its top left).